# How can I override a method with a dependent return type?

Tags: scala, scala-2.9, path-dependent-type

I'm having trouble in Scala 2.9.2 implementing a method which declares a dependent return type. The following code

```
object DependentTypesQuestion {
  def ??? = throw new UnsupportedOperationException
  trait X {
    trait Y
  }
  trait Z {
    def z(x: X): x.Y
  }
  object Z extends Z {
    override def z(x: X): x.Y = ???
  }
}
```

under 2.9.2 produces the following error message during compilation:

```
overriding method z in trait Z of type (x: DependentTypesQuestion.X)x.Y;  method z has incompatible type
```

In 2.10.0-M4 the problem seems to have been fixed, but unfortunately my project is tied to 2.9 for now.

> Is it possible to work around this issue in 2.9.2?

(Alternatively, is there any prospect of a 2.9.3 which would include the backported fix from 2.10?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're really stuck with 2.9.x then the following might be a workaround for you,

```
object DependentTypesQuestion {
  def ??? = throw new UnsupportedOperationException
  trait X {
    trait Y
  }
  trait Z[D[_ <: X with Singleton]] {
    def z[T <: X with Singleton](x: T): D[T]
  }

  type Dep[T <: X with Singleton] = T#Y

  object Z extends Z[Dep] {
    override def z[T <: X with Singleton](x: T): x.Y = ???
  }
}
```

Comment: I see. Unfortunately in my real case the object Z was an internal implementation, and outside consumers only see the trait Z, so this doesn't achieve the typing I'm really after.

Comment: Time to attempt escaping 2.9, I guess.